# Compute increase between rows for each same ID

Tags: r

A have a sorted data frame and I would like to compute the increase of `x2` for each same ID.
The input is already sorted in a certain manner:

```
ID    x2   x3  x4 
1    10   11   2  
2   100   12   4   
1    20   13  10 
7    24    3   1 
1    30   14   0   
3     6   15   1   
2    90   15   1
```

I would like to get:

```
ID    x2   increase x3  x4 
1    10            11   2  
2   100            12   4   
1    20      +100% 13  10 
7    24             3   1 
1    30       +50% 14   0   
3     6            15   1   
2    90       -10% 15   1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="
ID    x2   x3  x4 
1    10   11   2  
2   100   12   4   
1    20   13  10 
7    24    3   1 
1    30   14   0   
3     6   15   1   
2    90   15   1")
df$increase <- ave(df$x2, df$ID, FUN = function(x) c(NA, diff(x)/head(x, -1))*100)
df$increase <- ifelse(is.na(df$increase), "", sprintf("%+.0f%%", df$increase))
df
#   ID  x2 x3 x4 increase
# 1  1  10 11  2         
# 2  2 100 12  4         
# 3  1  20 13 10    +100%
# 4  7  24  3  1         
# 5  1  30 14  0     +50%
# 6  3   6 15  1         
# 7  2  90 15  1     -10%
```

Comment: could you give explanations for this instruction `df$increase <- ave(df$x2, df$ID, FUN = function(x) c(NA, diff(x)/head(x, -1))*100)` in your answer?

Comment: `ave` is splitting your data by `df$ID` and returning a vector of  length `nrow(df)`. The first split, `x` is `c(10L, 20L, 30L)`, `diff(x)` is `c(10L, 10L)`
and `head(x, 1)` is `c(10L, 20L)`. Dividing them gives your increase. I'm adding `NA` because the 1st value has no increase.